# Discord.js bot not going online using Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord, discord.js

I just started using JS to program a bot using Discord.js and Heroku to host it

On Heroku the build succeed but it won't go online. I use dotenv as Heroku asks

I installed dotenv using npm and that's my code for the dotenv:

```
require('dotenv').config();
console.log(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
```

The `console.log(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN)` returns `undefined` in the console.

This is my .env file:

```
DISCORD_TOKEN = OTI2M...
```

And this is where I use `DISCORD_TOKEN` in my code:

```
const token = process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN;

client.login(token);
```

The build fail in local saying this:

```
Error [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid token was provided.
```

On Heroku it build successfully but not in local with `node index.js`

This is the console log from Heroku and I'm sure I configured correctly the env variables in Heroku

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 14.x...
       Downloading and installing node 14.18.2...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.15
       
-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json)
       audited 132 packages in 0.767s
       
       18 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       found 0 vulnerabilities
       
       
-----> Build
       
-----> Caching build
       - node_modules
       
-----> Pruning devDependencies
       audited 132 packages in 0.791s
       
       18 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       found 0 vulnerabilities
       
       
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> worker
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 69.7M
-----> Launching...
       Released v15
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

> I use dotenv as Heroku asks

I'm not sure what you mean by this. Heroku has no such requirement. It can be convenient to use in development, but Heroku uses [config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) for configuration.

The good news is that both dotenv and config vars do the same thing: populate [environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable). The code you have referencing `process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN` *reads* the `DISCORD_TOKEN` environment variable.

The only step you appear to be missing is to set your `DISCORD_TOKEN` on the Heroku side. You can set a Heroku config var on the command line, [e.g.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-config-set)

```
heroku config:set DISCORD_TOKEN=some_token_value
```

or [using the web-based dashboard](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#using-the-heroku-dashboard).

Note that your `.env` file should *not* be tracked in your repository. It is only for local development.

Comment: Thansk for the feedback, I used the web-based dashboard to set the config variable for the token: KEY = DISCORD_TOKEN and VALUE = token. Should I remove "const token = process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN" from my code ? Why isn't it building correctly in local ?

Comment: And why is my console returning "undefined" with console.log(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN) ?

Comment: No, you need to use `process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN` to _read_ the environment variable. I don't know the context for your second comment, but assuming you mean on Heroku it's probably because you weren't _setting_ that value as a config var. And I don't know why it isn't working locally. Ask _one_ question at a time, please. Are you currently trying to get this working _locally_, or _on Heroku_? The build log in your question suggests the latter.

Comment: The second comment is form my console, not from Heroku. On Heroku the build deploy successfully.

Comment: @Davide, so your question is how to get this working _locally_?

Comment: Nope, I can't figure out why on Heroku the build complete without error and why I can't start it locally with the error wrote above. And also why the build completes but the bot is not online on Discord

Comment: Well if you've set the environment variable via a config var your code will be able to get it via `process.env` on Heroku. If you're trying to access it _locally_ you need to set the variable locally. Using dotenv is one possible way to do that. Is your `.env` file called that, _exactly_? There's no other extension or anything? I don't think there should be spaces in the content. Change `DISCORD_TOKEN = OTI2M...` to `DISCORD_TOKEN=OTI2M...`. Believe it or not, that's a vital difference in some shells like bash. If that works, let me know and I'll change my answer.

Comment: I tried everything you said. Still nothing both locally and on Heroku. (But on Heroku the build succeed).

Comment: Unless you're trying to use `DISCORD_TOKEN` during your build (which is unlikely) the build succeeding is irrelevant. What is the actual _problem_ you're trying to solve here? Please read [ask].

Comment: Update: I removed the .env file and the bot token is now as before the .env so, locally it works, the bot goes online and works fine. Now the problem is with Heroku, the build goes well, the worker is online, the bot is deployed but it is not going online on Discord. Now the application logs on Heroku shows the application crashed, should I open a new question, closing this one ?

Comment: THANKS EVERYONE, I FINALLY SOLVED, this question can be closed now. I was missing the node version in the package.json. I also removed the .env file and added the token as a string in the code directly, thanks everyone